# can I alloc() in the main thread and free() in another?

Tags: pthreads, mingw, mingw32

I have a program that runs fine on MacOS and Linux and cross-compiles to Windows with mingw. Recently I made the program multi-threaded.

The current design of the program has memory allocated in the main thread and freed in the slave "worker" threads. That's not a problem on MacOS and Linux because the malloc/free system is multi-threaded.

I'm concerned about the cross-compiling, however. The version of mingw that I'm using is built from MacOS ports. It's a pretty ancient version of G++ (version 3.4.5) from 2004. I've been unsuccessful in my attempts to build a more recent version (I'd like to build a 64-bit version, but gave up). I'm getting pthreads from http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32.

My concern is that the malloc & free system in 3.4.5 is not multi-threaded.

Questions:

1. Should I rewrite my program so that the blocks of memory to be freed are passed back to the main thread to be freed there?
2. Should I try to upgrade to a more recent mingw?
3. Is there any way to find these concurrency problems other than massive amounts of testing? That just doesn't feel good to me.

Thanks!

Comment: So in retrospect I've concluded that option #1 doesn't work, because there are many other cases in the threads where malloc() and free() need to be called. I could give each thread it's own memory allocator, but that's the wrong direction to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you say malloc & free are not multithreaded?

mingw32 by default will link with msvcrt.dll which is a multithread dll. See [1]. There **was**[2] a single-threaded library provided by Microsoft, but it was only available for static linking.

PS: You mention that you are cross-compiling but you seem instead to be compiling the windows program in windows. In such case, Why don't you dowload the binaries from www.mingw.org? (it's a pain to figure out in their downloads the files needed, though)

1- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

2- See [1]. Removed in Visual Studio 2005 http:// msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: In fact, this is the correct answer, and this is the way I implemented the system. I am allocating in the producer thread and freeing in the consumer thread. malloc and free are multithreaded. It all works perfectly. It's very clean.

Comment: And, to continue the comment, I was originally cross-compiling from my Mac to Windows with the Mingw version 3.x compiler. But the 4.x compiler is better and it only runs hosted, so I downloaded the binaries and they work fine.  But it does make compiling a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would avoid this. It sounds like you're trying to dodge the main issue.
2. Yes, that would be a good idea in any case...
3. One way to detect concurrency problems related to memory allocation/deallocation is a memory leak detector. I'm not sure if valgrind works on cygwin.

Comment: I'm not using cygwin, I'm using mingw.  I'd be thrilled to upgrade to a more recent version. Any idea how to build it on Mac or Linux? According to http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW, "As of this writing, the MinGW Project does not support any official build of GCC, more recent than GCC-3.4.5, for use as a cross hosted MinGW development tool, on any platform. This is unlikely to change, until after an officially supported stable GCC-4.x version has been released, for native use on the MS-Windows platform."

Comment: Ick, that's disappointing, considering how many years that GCC 4 has been around. Are there any characteristics of your application that prevent you from using Microsoft tools when on Windows?

Comment: The program builds with GNU flex, automake, and other tools. I've maintained code in the past that cross-compiles on VC++ and GCC but the VC++ version is always behind. The nice thing about mingw and cygwin is that you can use the identical tool chains to deliver a program on both platforms. I'm going to spend a *long* time trying to find a multithreading solution with Mingw or Cygwin before giving that up.

Comment: Then I suppose the only really viable solution is to stick with your current toolchain and try to find a workaround, like the same-thread allocation/deallocation that you mentioned.